# Timeout webservice call from client side

Tags: java, rest, timeout, resteasy

I'm calling a webservice using RestEasy Client. One requirement is to abort/timeout the call if it runs for more that 5 seconds. How would I achieve this with RestEasy Client? I have only seen server side timeout, i.e. the Rest Easy websevice will timeout the request if it's not fulfilled within a certain time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A RESTEasy client typically uses Apache HttpClient to handle the network conversation.

You can override the HttpClient properties with your own custom timeout parameters:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, connectionTimeoutMillis);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, socketTimeoutMillis);
```

The first param allows you to specify timeout establishing the initial connection and the second allows you to specify the maximum period of time in which a socket will wait while no data is sent.

You can use the modified HttpClient to build your ClientExecutor:

```
ClientExecutor executor = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(httpClient);
```

Which can be used in turn to build a ClientRequest object.  Or you can inject it into a RestClientProxyFactoryBean if you are using a Spring configuration for RESTEasy.

It's not exactly the same as an absolute 5 second timeout, but depending on what you are trying to accomplish, tweaking these two properties will usually fill the bill.

Comment: How do we handle it? I mean I want to log if timeout occurs.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer the builder pattern here is how you do it:

```
 Client client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .establishConnectionTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .socketTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
```

taken from here: http://blog.eisele.net/2014/12/setting-timeout-for-jax-rs-20-resteasy-client.html

Comment: Currently both methods are deprecated

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Carter Page is correct for Apache HttpClient version >= 4.0.

For earlier versions of HttpClient (e.g. 3.1) the code is slightly different:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams params = httpClient.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams();
params.setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeoutMillis);
params.setSoTimeout(socketTimeoutMillis);

ClientExecutor executor = new ApacheHttpClientExecutor(httpClient);
MyService service = ProxyFactory.create(MyService.class, URL, executor);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using resteasy client framework with spring integration ([documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#spring_client_proxy)), the following is the way to set timeout values:

```
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient">
    <property name="params" ref="httpParams"/>
</bean>

<bean id="httpParams" class="org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams"/>

<bean id="httpConnectionParams" class="org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParamBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpParams"/>
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="10000"/>
    <property name="soTimeout" value="30000"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that both **establishConnectionTimeout** and **socketTimeout** are deprecated.

With this explanation on jboss v7.3 by [redhat website](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html-single/developing_web_services_applications/index) :

> The following ClientBuilder specification-compliant methods replace certain deprecated RESTEasy methods:
>
> - The **connectTimeout** method replaces the **establishConnectionTimeout** method.
>
>   - The **connectTimeout** method determines how long the client must wait when making a new server connection.
> - The **readTimeout** method replaces the **socketTimeout** method.
>
>   - The **readTimeout** method determines how long the client must wait for a response from the server.

This worked for me with **RestEASY 3.12.1.Final**:

```
    private Client clientBuilder() {
        return new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    }
```