# how to increase the Rest service timeout time in spring STS

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, service

I am using a spring STS to develop the project which  has the embedded tc server.  I don't know what causes this  issue, but my rest service always gets timeout of 60 seconds, even though I tried to keep timeout=100 in @Transactional and I tried putting the value in *jpa*.xml file too. Can anybody tell me how to increase the timeout?

Comment: Are you saying you need to increase the server time out for STS which has embeded tomcat server?

Comment: ha, yes pradeep

Comment: Service timeout? It must be a `read time out` on the client, then? Or does your `JPA` query time out at 60 seconds but you are still expecting your client to wait for the result?

Comment: yes Zilvinas , JPA query timed out at 60 seconds even thought I have nowhere mentioned it

Comment: Hello Dhari,Hope my answer helped you .If yes please accept the answer if not please let me know so that I can improvise on that help you to give  a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using RestTemplate than you should use following code to implement timeouts

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
}

private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setReadTimeout(2000);
    factory.setConnectTimeout(2000);
    return factory;
}}
The x
```

ml configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
<constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"
        p:readTimeout="2000"
        p:connectTimeout="2000" />
</constructor-arg>
```

Ref :
[Spring Boot REST API - request timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852236/spring-boot-rest-api-request-timeout)

[Timeout webservice call from client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965917/timeout-webservice-call-from-client-side)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hello Dhari,

Please double click on the embedded tomcat server .You can modify the time out seconds as per your wish. Please look at the screen shot provided.

```
More over your question is not related to increase the service timeout instead it should be server timeout which was pretty fishy to understand.Kindly update your question as suggested.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer pradeep. I thought there may be any relation bw server timeout and rest service timeout, but not.  Now My problem is whenever I  called my rest service it's always timed out at 60 seconds even thought I kept timeout=100 at the top of the class, can U tell me what to do